# code designed to remove NaN from array, still returns NaN JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I need to remove all empty values (null, undefined, '', NaN, false) EXCEPT 0 from an array.  eg: [0, false, [], undefined, {}, NaN, 'Kevin'] => [0, [], {}, 'Kevin'];

```
function removeBlank(array) {
  array = array.filter(function (n) {
    return (n !== undefined && n !== null && n !== false && n !== "" && isNaN()!= NaN); });
  console.log( array );
}
```

However this still returns a NaN. 
for example
`removeBlank([0, NaN, undefined, false, '', null, 'Kevin']);`
 returns 
 [0, NaN, "Kevin"]

How do I improve the isNaN()!= NaN) to remove NaN with out removing strings, ZEROS or other numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isNaN()!= NaN` has no meaning, [**`isNaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is a function that takes a parameter and check (return `true` or `false`) if it's a valid number or not, you are not passing to it anything.

And even if you use it right, it won't work, because then all values that are not numbers will be filtered out.

I'd suggest using this:

```
array = array.filter(function (n) {
    return n || n === 0;
});
```

either `n` is truthy or it is `0`.

Comment: @MaxES `logical OR`, it means either side is `true` or truthy. If `n !== false !== "" !== 0 !== NaN !== undefined !== null` then it's truthy and then `n` is equivalent to `true` so the test is ok. If `n === 0` then the left side of `||` will be equivalent to `false`, but the right side `n === 0` will be `true`, `||` need only one `true` side to be `true`. So either `n` is truthy or it is equal to `0`.

Comment: @MaxES Here is more about [**logical operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: If it's `Infinity` or `-Infinity` it will return `true`. Usually it is a bad idea to work with infinite numbers, almost no application deals with them.

Comment: @arboreal84 I'm not sure what you are talking about?

Comment: @arboreal84 both `Infinity` and `-Infinity` are truthy as they should be.

Comment: Very rarely you will want to work with infinite numbers. If you really want to work with infinite numbers you should still express that intent clearly in your code.

Comment: @arboreal84 Where did I ever mentioned infinite number. My answer is neither explicitly nor implicitly related to infinite numbers. Are you sure you've read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN` takes the number as a parameter. Needs to be `isNaN(n)`

Then, unless you want to work with infinite numbers, like `-Infinity` and `Infinity`, I recommend you just validate with:

```
arr.filter(function (n) {
   return isFinite(n);
});
```

`NaN` is not finite so it would be filtered too.
`NaN` also has the property that any comparison will make it return `false`. This means `n == n` will return `false` if `n` is `NaN`.

Comment: `Infinity` should be truthy. I guess.

Comment: `Infinity` is not a number that you can operate with other numbers other than for the purposes of comparison. In that sense, `Infinity` almost always breaks business logic.